How do ethical intuitionists avoid relativism?
Why doesn't ethical intuitionism (the form which actually uses intuition as the foundation of morality rather than some other non-inferential method) fall into relativism? It seems that different people from different cultures and different times have very different moral intuitions. In some cultures and time periods, infanticide has been pretty normalised for example, and I would imagine that those who engaged in it didn't have too much of a moral intuition against it. We can see the same thing with attitudes on homosexuality changing across time in the West. I have even noticed in myself a huge reduction in moral intuition since I got into ethics and started viewing morality analytically. I'm also pretty sure I have significantly less empathy and general emotion than the average person, and this contributed to me having less moral intuition.
So, how does the intuitionist balance these or find one intuition to privilege in finding one absolute moral truth? If we base moral truth in intuition then shouldn't different intuitions warrant different moral truths depending on the agent's moral intuition?

Ethical intuitions are fallible and muddied by personal and cultural biases, like all intuitions and perceptions, and some of apparent ethical diversity is also attributable to non-moral interpretations and judgments, see SEP. Ethical intuitionists hold that intuitions, nonetheless, pick out something real, and can be refined and developed, sharpened by rational analysis, etc., also like all intuitions and perceptions. There is no path to relativism here. But "privileging" is gradual and "absolute moral truth" is just an aspiration

Intuitiionism couldn't avoid or address the arguments presented by relativism. It's absolute morality vs. relative morality. It's why intuitionism fell out of favor..

Let me try to answer the interesting question!!!I can share my thought from the perspective of classical intuitionism.
Let’s start with “basic propositions”,in classic intuitionism ,they see all basic moral propositions as self-evident things.So all people who make moral judgments based on intuition will agree with these basic moral propositions.[See：SEP，intuitionism in ethics 1.2,Sidgwick’s opinion ”attract general consensus(1874/1967, 338)”]Therefore ,in ideal situations ,we will never disagree on basic propositions.
It seems that different people from different cultures and different times have very different moral intuitions..Yes,it’s easy to find there are many moral disagreements in our daily lives ,but in intuitionists’ view,they are not really moral disagreements.According to SEP,they have several different methods.I sort them into two kinds .
First ,shift the disagreement,it’s typified by claiming that moral disagreement stems from disagreement about non-moral facts.Except that,William David Ross said it is simply a difference in judgement about the application of agreed moral principles(in the above text,I called them “basic propositions “), he use a more conservative from of intuitionism.In this theory,intuitionism simply means that only basic propositions are self-evident, complicated moral scenes are not self-evident.Similar,another explanation of it is that moral disagreement does not imply that people have different intuitions,just imply that they have different beliefs. The source of these different beliefs is the different interpretations or applications of the same moral intuitions.
The other kind is making the weakness appear in the persons.Some Intuitionists allowed that stupidity,    corruption, or perverseness may make one doubt self-evident propositions.It’s also possible,someone can’t grasp intuition because intuition is faint and obscure.And,still Ross, “Ross notes that self-evident propositions may only be evident to us once we reach a certain moral maturity (1930/2002, 29).”(SEP ).
All of the above is inspired by SEP :https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/intuitionism-ethics/.

Right, once one knows enough, everything is obvious. We just need a method to reliably cultivate this knowledge in persons over time so that we always have enough Solomons around. Simpliciter!
